# AngularJS и $http

Tags: php, http, angularjs

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему не работает эта функция?

```
$scope.send = function () {
        $http.post('http://localhost/html/index.php', { foo: 'bar' }).success(function(response){
            alert("Удачно");
        }).error(function(){
            alert("Ошибка");  
        });
}
```

index.php

```
<?php
echo 1;
?>
```

Однако после выполнения этой функции ВООБЩЕ ничего не происходит, ни сообщение об ошибке, ни сообщение, что успешно выполнено, вообще ничего. (

В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Откройте в браузере отладчик, откройте вкладку network, выполните действие, и посмотрите, что уходит от  клиента и что приходит от сервера. Если не происходит вообще ничего, то, скорей всего, ваш JS код просто не выполняется.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/4Leb7gkz/1/), который с вашим кодом ошибку нормально выдаёт, может, из него поймёте, что у вас не так.